# Get the coordinates from CirclePolygon in matplotlib.patches

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code, which generates a circle polygon (A polygon-approximation of a circle patch.) using Python matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import CirclePolygon

circle = CirclePolygon((0, 0), radius = 0.75, fc = 'y')
plt.gca().add_patch(circle)
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

For the code above, I have the output given below:
[image: CirclePolygon]

I need all the points that are together forming the circle polygon. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Polygon is based on a path. You may get this path via `circle.get_path()`. You're interested in the `vertices` of this path. 
Finally you need to transform them according to the Polygon's transform.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import CirclePolygon

circle = CirclePolygon((0, 0), radius = 0.75, fc = 'y')
plt.gca().add_patch(circle)

verts = circle.get_path().vertices
trans = circle.get_patch_transform()
points = trans.transform(verts)
print(points)

plt.plot(points[:,0],points[:,1])
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

The blue line is a plot of the thus obtained points.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The transformation to get the path of the patch back in user data coordinates is different before adding the patch an axes than after adding the patch to an axes. Before adding to an axes, the *patch.get_transform.transform(vertices)* yields the data in user coordinates, after adding the patch it yields points in display coordinates. To transform the points back to user add (chain) the following transform *ax.stransData.inverted().transform(points)*. See the two functions. It cost me a lot of confusing, but now it makes perfectly sense.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Arrow

def get_data_before_adding_to_axes(a_patch):
    """Return true data from Patch Path before adding patch to an axes"""
    verts = a_patch.get_path().vertices
    return a_patch.get_transform().transform(verts)

def get_data_after_adding_to_axes(a_patch, ax=None):
    """Return true data from Patch Path after adding patch to an axes"""
    verts = a_patch.get_path().vertices
    points = a_patch.get_transform().transform(verts) # not screen coordinates
    return ax.transData.inverted().transform(points) # requires extra transform

# Instantiate 2 differnt type of patches:
circle = Circle((-0.5, 1), radius = 0.2, fc = 'y')
arrow  = Arrow(0, 1, 0, -1, fc='b')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

print("Before adding the patches to the axes:")
for a_patch, its_name in zip([circle, arrow], ['circle', 'arrow']):
    xy = get_data_before_adding_to_axes(a_patch)
    print(its_name, ' :\n', xy)
    ax.plot(*xy.T, color='orange', ls='solid', lw=4)

ax.add_patch(circle)
ax.add_patch(arrow)

print("\nAfter adding the patches to the axes:")
for a_patch, its_name in zip([circle, arrow], ['circle', 'arrow']):
    xy = get_data_after_adding_to_axes(a_patch, ax=ax)
    print(its_name, ' :\n', xy)
    ax.plot(*xy.T, 'o', color='red', ls='dashed', lw=1)
```

[image: Result, showing the patches and their outlines plotted from their tranformed paths]

​